# Playing Individual instance animation?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to randomly create multiple instances of an object on points.
When one of theses instances "spawns" randomly, I want it to play an animation, something like a scaling transform before disappearing...

Then, when the next instance "spawns" it would play the same scaling animation from the start (resetting the scaling transform for each instance spawn).
I would like this process to repeat over and over.

My problem is when I use the "#frame value driver" to increase scale, the scaling animation plays only from the start of the timeline and it doesn't repeat when the next instance appear...
How could I solve this?

Here is an example of what I want (made it manually with keyframes outside of Geometry Nodes).

[image]